# John Guttag Finger Exercise Chapter 10

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, binary

This code is from Guttag's introduction to programming. Finger exercise for section 10.3:

```
def search(L, e):
    """Assumes L is a list, the elements of which are in
     ascending order.
     Returns True if e is in L and False otherwise"""

     def bSearch(L, e, low, high):
         #Decrements high - low
         if high == low:
             return L[low] == e
         mid = (low + high)//2
         if L[mid] == e:
             return True
         elif L[mid] > e:
             if low == mid: #nothing left to search
                 return False
              else:
                 return bSearch(L, e, low, mid - 1)
         else:
             return bSearch(L, e, mid + 1, high)

     if len(L) == 0:
         return False
     else:
         return bSearch(L, e, 0, len(L) - 1)
```

I'm not wrapping my head around recursion. Why does this use `mid+1` instead of `mid` in the 2<sup>nd</sup> recursive call?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your Python code was not indented at all. As you know, indentation is part of the syntax of Python, so please take care to represent Python code correctly. I have added indentation: please verify it is as you intended it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a binary search, so on each recursion you split the list in half. If you get to the point of making a recursive call, you've already checked the element at `mid`, and it isn't what you're looking for (if it had been, you would have returned `true`, and wouldn't need to recur). Therefore, you pick a direction in which to search (a half of the list in which to search), and search that half recursively. However, regardless of which half you pick, *you already know the element at the `mid` index is not the one you're looking for*, so you never need to check it again, so you don't need to include it as part of the list you're recurring on.